# Error on Angular.forEach with value.split is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I want to take the response of $HTTP and map it in to an empty object. Here what i have tried

The main Code

```
function myData( myUrl) {
         $http({
                method: 'POST',
                 url: "http://localhost:8085/api/foo",
                data: $scope.myUrl,     
        })
         .then(
            function successCall(response) {
                $scope.resultForRecord=response;
                $scope.obj=[];
                angular.forEach(response,function (valueToObj,key) {
                $scope.obj.push(
                    {'key' : $scope.resultForRecord.toString().split("=")[0],'value' : $scope.resultForRecord.toString().split("=")[1]})});
                        console.log($scope.obj);
            },
            function errorCall(response) {                            
                console.log(response);
                $scope.resultForRecord=response;
            });
        }
```

And the error is **valueToObj.split is not a function**

now i have tried on hard coded practice demo. that worked fine. here is the demo

DEMO:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

       $scope.dataSet=[
          "jon=12",
          "petter=10",
          "sara=8"
      ];
      $scope.obj=[];
      angular.forEach($scope.dataSet,function (key,value) {
          $scope.obj.push(
              {'name' : key.split("=")[0],'age' : key.split("=")[1]}
            );
    });

      console.log($scope.dataSet);
      console.log($scope.obj);
  });
```

How can i fix this? thanks in advance

Comment: Your code isn't complete, so we're forced to guess. My guess is that you want to split every element of the array you get as the **data** of the HTTP response. But you're split every value of the HTTP response object (status, headers, data, etc.). Simply using your debugger, or logging the value of response, would help. You seem to have done that, but you haven't posted what is logged either.

Comment: updated sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.forEach(response, function(valueToObj, key) {
  $scope.obj.push(
    {
      'key' : $scope.resultForRecord.toString().split("=")[0],
      'value' : $scope.resultForRecord.toString().split("=")[1]
    }
  );
});
```

I reformatted your code to make it clearer.

Read that code:

1. You're iterating over all the fields of `response`. `response` is the HTTP response object, which has 4 fields: status (a number), headers, data, config. You actually want to iterate over the elements of the JSON object sent as the **body** of the response (`response.data`);
2. You're not even doing anything with the current element inside the function. Instead of splitting `valueToObj`, you're splitting `$scope.resultForRecord.toString()`. So you're splitting the same thing multiple times, and that thing is the string representation, once again, of the whole HTTP response.

What you most probably want is:

```
angular.forEach(response.data, function(element) {
  $scope.obj.push(
    {
      'key' : element.split("=")[0],
      'value' : element.split("=")[1]
    }
  );
});
```

Or, cleaner:

```
$scope.obj = response.data.map(function(element) {
  var parts = element.split("=");
  return {
    key: parts[0],
    value: parts[1]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.split requires a string.

You are iterating over an array using ..

```
valueToObj.split
```

this assumes on EVERY iteration valueToObj is a string. However, if it is not a string then the function will not exist and you will get this error. This is because the split function only exists on strings.